# Does the converse of if $x$ is a transitive set then $\bigcup (x^{+})=x$ hold?

Tags: set-theory

I am studying Set Theory from the book Set Theory: A First Course by Daniel W. Cunningham. This proves that [If $x$ is a transitive set, $\bigcup x^+ = x$, where $x^+ = x\cup\{x\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98088/if-x-is-a-transitive-set-bigcup-x-x-where-x-x-cup-x). I really wonder if the converse is true. I tried proving it but got stuck. I couldn't find counterexamples either.

Suppose $a \in x$. Then $a\in y$ for some $y\in x^{+}$. Then $y=x$ or $y\in x$. If $y = x$ then we're done. Suppose $y\ne x$ then $y\in x$. What happens then?

Hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\bigcup x^+ = (\bigcup x)\cup x,$ so $\bigcup x^+ = x$ means that $\bigcup x \subseteq x,$ which we can see implies (actually is equivalent to) transitivity: If $y\in x$ and $z\in y,$ then $z\in \bigcup x,$ so $z\in x.$

Comment: But then does $\bigcup x^{+} $ equals $x$?

Comment: @AshishK I badly misunderstood the question. The converse is true.